# Does a polygon in a layer intersect with another polygon in the same layer

Tags: shapefile, spatial-database, gml, overlay

I am a CS major with little experience in GIS. I am working on vector polygon overlay. Looking at GML and shapefile data, I realized that a map is made up of a large number of polygons. Does a polygon in a map intersect with another polygon in the same map? In other words, is it correct to assume that no two polygons in one map intersect with one another? It is very difficult to verify this by looking at the vertices of the polygon because of the sheer size of the files.

Comment: I sense a bit of a language issue here. Are you asking *how* to find out whether two polygons intersect?

Comment: @blah238 i have modified to clarify my question.

Comment: It is certainly possible and indeed often necessary for polygons to overlap depending on the nature and *purpose* of the data. I still am not seeing a real question here.

Comment: @blah238 There can be overlapping features in a map for example two rivers represented as polygons can criss-cross as such producing overlap. But it is not mandatory to create overlapping polygons for this. The two rivers can be represented as 3 polygons; 2 polygons for original river and 1 for the intersecting polygons.

Comment: Your example kind of proves my point -- it's all up to how the data was designed and entered. So what are you getting at? Is there an actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @blah238 This is out of curiosity. I have heard about ArcGIS but not used.

Comment: Justin, there are many distinct senses in which polygons can "intersect". To help clarify your question, you might be interested in [learning more about relationships among spatial features](http://delab.csd.auth.gr/~alex/sdb/artSSD93.pdf) or perhaps in [how ArcGIS views intersection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002q000000.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are describing is known as **coplanar polygons** - shapefiles are more likely to keep two polygons in separate "planes", i.e. no intersections created, but the [**Union**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000s000000) tool can be used to planarize them.

Comment: Unless you are talking about PolygonZM's with different Z values all polygons in a projected coordinate system are coplanar.

Comment: I don't know what else you would call that other than "intersecting" polygons, BTW.

Comment: Coplanar polygons are ARC/INFO (ArcInfo Workstation) speak for the way polygons are stored in coverage format where there was no support for loop topology.  It led to overlapping polygons being modelled using region topology.  All came long before Zs and Ms got stored with X,Y.  Another relevant term may planar enforcement which coverages required but shapefiles do not.

Comment: Ah, you are talking about this then: [Overlapping polygons in a coverage: Regions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001300000036000000)

Comment: Yep - you'll see my name on a 1992 region topology paper/presentation referenced in this [one](http://www.geog.ucsb.edu/~good/papers/414.pdf).

Comment: @blah238 thanks, the links and discussions are helpful, if you could edit your answer to reflect yes or no to the question, we can close it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you were referring to me or @PolyGeo, but as it stands this is not a yes/no question. As such you get an "it depends" answer.

Comment: @blah238 I agree I'm still only guessing at what the question being asked is and thus "taking a stab" at the answer.